# Ruby on Rails : how to implement Cancel button in form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a basic form using the form_tag helper working fine, but I want to add a cancel button, what is the syntax for doing this?  I want the cancel button to appear as a button, not a link, then take the user to a different URL (indicating they don't want to submit the form).

TY,
Fred

Comment: what do you want it to do?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to clear/reset the form fields, do what weltschmerz suggests.

However, I'd generally expect a Cancel button to not clear the form, but to take me away from the form, meaning I don't plan on submitting it.

If you want the latter, I'd just make a link (or button) to the page you want to go to upon cancelling, such as :

```
=link_to 'Cancel', my_page_path
```

Or if you want a button:

```
= button_tag "Cancel", :type => 'button'
```

Then add this to your controller:

```
# before_filter for Rails 4.x and prior
before_action :check_for_cancel, :only => [:create, :update]

def check_for_cancel
  if params[:commit] == "Cancel"
    redirect_to my_page_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Will the above make the Cancel link show up as a button?  That's what I'd like.

Comment: Thanks, looks good, I am getting the error "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `button_tag' for #<#<Class:0xb2a2f898>:0xb2a2e4d4>):" now however, looks like it doesn't like the button_tag element?

Comment: I was able to use a `submit_tag` for the same purpose.

Answer (score 34):

If you mean a reset button, paste the following inside your form:

```
<%= button_tag "Reset", type: :reset %>
```

Tested it, it works fine and resets all fields in the form.

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear, I don't want to reset the fields, I cancel to abort the form and go to a different url.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a submit tag, I would suggest a `<button>` tag, because the parameter `:commit` might be localised, thus making it a pain to evaluate in the controller.

A `button_tag` can have a name/value like any other field, so you can basically create a flag with it.

The following code is what I would use:

**in the view:**

```
<%= button_tag t('buttons.cancel'), type: "submit", name: "cancel", value: true %>
```

**in the controller:**

```
before_filter :redirect_cancel, only: [:create, :update]

private

def redirect_cancel
  redirect_to my_page_path if params[:cancel]
end
```

Much cleaner imho, because you rely on a flag instead of a (potentially) localised display value.

Answer (score 1):

[`button_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) seems a simple way to achieve the same, but it has to be put outside of the form itself, but that can easily be fixed with css.

Also, to solve this in a more generic way (also working for editing nested resources on a resource that has not been persisted yet), you can create a separate form for the cancel that contains all the original values as hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

Short and easy.

```
<%= link_to "Cancel", show_page %>
```