# Clear Form in Rails(Not Reset Form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, button

I want to create a button that just clears the entire form, not reset it.  I currently have this, but it just resets the form to what it was right after the form submission.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14313638/6665421

Let me know if that is what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add some JavaScript to target each input and use the correct js function to set them. For most inputs you can just use

`$("#id_for_input").val("")`

So you will need to create so js that looks similar to this

```
$("#clear_form_button").on("click", function() {
  $("#first_input").val("");
  $("#second_input").val("");
  $("#third_input").val("");
  $("#fourth_input").val("");
});
```